# Separando um dataframe por algum criterio - Python Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Tenho um arquivo em csv com pocuo mais de 500 mil linhas que gostaria de separar em dois dataframes.

O formato de cada linha:
data, hora, valor da variavel de interesse

dd-mm-aa,hh:mm:00,float

As linhas sao gravadas a cada minuto. Portando em uma ano sao: 526.600 linhas.

Gostaria de fazer um 'split' separando o dia da noite, ou seja, baseado nos intervalos das horas. 08:00:00 ate 20:00:00 ter um df e outro para a noite.

Como fazer isso usando o pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo os seguintes dados para esta resposta, salvos no arquivo `'dados.csv'`:

```
data,hora,numero
01/01/2018,10:30,0.1
01/01/2018,20:05,0.2
01/01/2018,07:00,0.3
02/01/2018,11:10,0.4
02/01/2018,22:35,0.5
03/01/2018,03:10,0.6
03/01/2018,20:45,0.7
03/01/2018,12:20,0.8
04/01/2018,15:15,0.9
04/01/2018,23:59,0.95
```

Ao carregar o *DataFrame*, especifique o tipo das colunas `data` e `hora` como datas, informando o nome das colunas no parâmetro `parse_dates` do comando [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('dados.csv', parse_dates=['data','hora'])
```

Saída:

```
Out[4]:
        data                hora  numero
0 2018-01-01 2018-06-02 10:30:00    0.10
1 2018-01-01 2018-06-02 20:05:00    0.20
2 2018-01-01 2018-06-02 07:00:00    0.30
3 2018-02-01 2018-06-02 11:10:00    0.40
4 2018-02-01 2018-06-02 22:35:00    0.50
5 2018-03-01 2018-06-02 03:10:00    0.60
6 2018-03-01 2018-06-02 20:45:00    0.70
7 2018-03-01 2018-06-02 12:20:00    0.80
8 2018-04-01 2018-06-02 15:15:00    0.90
9 2018-04-01 2018-06-02 23:59:00    0.95
```

Para transformar a coluna `hora` em formato de hora:

```
df['hora'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hora']).dt.time
```

Saída:

```
Out[6]:
        data      hora  numero
0 2018-01-01  10:30:00    0.10
1 2018-01-01  20:05:00    0.20
2 2018-01-01  07:00:00    0.30
3 2018-02-01  11:10:00    0.40
4 2018-02-01  22:35:00    0.50
5 2018-03-01  03:10:00    0.60
6 2018-03-01  20:45:00    0.70
7 2018-03-01  12:20:00    0.80
8 2018-04-01  15:15:00    0.90
9 2018-04-01  23:59:00    0.95
```

Para criar o *DataFrame* com os dados do período "dia", informe a condição 'hora' entre 8 e 20 no filtro da consulta:

```
df_dia = df.loc[(df['hora'] >= datetime.time(hour=8)) & (df['hora'] <= datetime.time(hour=20))]
```

Resultado:

```
In [9]: df_dia
Out[9]:
        data      hora  numero
0 2018-01-01  10:30:00     0.1
3 2018-02-01  11:10:00     0.4
7 2018-03-01  12:20:00     0.8
8 2018-04-01  15:15:00     0.9
```

Para criar o *DataFrame* noite, basta informar a condição contrária:

```
df_noite = df.loc[(df['hora'] < datetime.time(hour=8)) | (df['hora'] > datetime.time(hour=20))]
```

Resultado:

```
In [12]: df_noite
Out[12]:
        data      hora  numero
1 2018-01-01  20:05:00    0.20
2 2018-01-01  07:00:00    0.30
4 2018-02-01  22:35:00    0.50
5 2018-03-01  03:10:00    0.60
6 2018-03-01  20:45:00    0.70
9 2018-04-01  23:59:00    0.95
```